# How Fluxes are garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, project-reactor

Let's imagine that I create a [Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html). This Flux has been given access to some resources during creation, and I'd like some cleanup to happen on `Cancel`/`Complete` (e.g. release some external resources). Eventually, I remove all pointers to this Flux, so it becomes available for garbage collection. What happens on garbage collection? Does my Flux receive a `Cancel` signal so it can perform cleanup?

Comment: It's always better to not rely on GC to do cleanups: you are not guaranteed that your object will ever be collected, as GC is allowed to postpone collecting indefinitely as long as there's available memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no particular cleanup mechanic tied to GC (the `Flux` won't receive a cancel signal when GCed)
- Note there is a factory operator called `Flux.using` that takes a resource supplier and a cleanup callback. Otherwise, you could use `doFinally` to perform the cleanup operation
- In both case, this is assuming the `Flux` isn't infinite (eg. a `Flux.create` that never calls `complete` nor `error`) or is cancelled.
- A `Flux` should usually be initialized on subscribe, so if nothing subscribed to it the resources probably haven't been initialized (once again, provided they are initialized in the `Flux.create` callback, otherwise your mileage may vary)

Comment: Even if `Flux` received something in finalization stage, it's still silly to rely on that for resource management.